# Facebook warnings in log

Tags: error, facebook, autoloader

I am keep getting below warnings :

```
ERR (3): Warning: include(FacebookApiException.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94

2015-06-11T11:20:13+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'FacebookApiException.php' for inclusion (include_path='/app/code/local:/app/code/community:/app/code/core:/lib:.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php')  in /lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
```

How can I track the source of this warning and how can this be fixed?
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If you want to debug this I can recommend xdebug, otherwise just search for "include(FacebookApiException.php)" in your project and try to fix this, it seems that is missing the path to the file, are you using composer?

Comment: Are you using any third party extension that ponints to facebook. In this case the extension is not installed properly

Comment: @lloiacono No, I am not using composer. And I have searched for "include(FacebookApiException.php)" but didn't find it anywhere in code files.

Comment: can you share some code that how you include you facebook php api

Comment: @Pratikbhatt Yes, I am using extensions that connects to facebook but the extension is working flawlessly.

Comment: Just disable the extension from xml and check if the warning vanishes just to confirm about the extension.

Comment: @ShaheerAli  I am using Magestore SocialLogin extension and AheadWorks FBConnector extension

Comment: try to give 777 rights to all the folders and look into the both extension folder that any one have (FacebookApiException.php) or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, first find if in your project if you have this file:

```
FacebookApiException.php
```

Then search in your whole project where this line is used:

```
include(FacebookApiException.php)
```

Then you can start to debug, but I'm pretty sure that you could try to reformulate that include to include the file path and file name, check if it works. Also check if you really need to use include or you should user require. Then try this:

```
include 'path/to/your/file/FacebookApiException.php';
```